# Variable file include path in Flash Pro when build an android app using Air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, package, apk

As far as I know, the only way to include a folder in an Air package (in Flash Pro, not Builder) is through the GUI:

> Publish Settings > Player Settings > General Tab > Included Files

... but it's kind of a huge hassle to manually add and remove folders over and over again if you have to publish the app with a dozen different versions of the content, you know?

Is there a way to conditionally include folders based on text somewhere - the app config xml, maybe? or something else that will be checked when the APK is compiled? That way I could just copy and paste in the folder name to switch which asset folder is being included, instead of going through the whole process inside of the flash IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea might possibly be of some use although it could require some management due to possibly meaning you have duplicated assets.

I typically store all my assets inside an 'includes' folder/directory and just add this to the Settings > Include Files pane.

I also have folders which store the target specific includes, such as 'IOS' and 'ANDROID', (but aren't added to the Include Files pane).

When publishing, I swap out the contents of the includes folder. So it's just a case of deleting the existing contents if the includes folder and copy/pasting from the relevant source folder into the includes folder.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yeah, swapping folders is what I've been doing - but it'd be really convenient if I could just change a few letters in an XML config doc or something.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do, though they're not 100% solutions per se.

**1) Use conditional compilation:**

Depending on how your imports/includes are set up, you could change it to always be the same file, but change the code/embed inside depending on a compile time constant. You can add a compile constant by going to *File > Publish Paramaters > Flash (tab) > Parameters > Configure Constants*:

[image: Adding compile constants in Flash Pro]

Your constants would be in the form `CONFIG::debug` or `FOO::bar`, then in code, you wrap your code like this:

```
CONFIG::debug
{
    // code is only included if CONFIG::debug is true at compile time
}
```

Then, by flipping constants, you can include or exclude blocks of code. There's a bit more detail here: http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_conditional_compilation

NOTE: this is much easier to do in an IDE like FlashDevelop.

**2) Use an external IDE**

Taking the FlashDevelop example, when building for mobile, a number of `.bat` files are created. Depending on the environment vars set, you can include/exclude folders as you wish. I do this to include different assets depending on if it's a desktop, Android, or iOS build.

**3) Use the Flex SDK command line or ANT**

With either of these, you can specify a config.xml file for the files that you want to include. External IDEs (like FD) use the command line directly, so you can almost copy/paste the command if necessary.

For ANT, it's not my strongest point, but you can find out a bit more here: http://charlespatricknewman.com/blog/?p=325

Comment: I would love to use something aside from the main Flash IDE, but for this project I'm stuck with it, due to this being a team effort, and wanting to keep it easy to add new developers with as little ramp up time as possible as far as the dev environment goes, as well as keeping it OS-agnostic (which FlashDevelop would go against.)

Your first suggestion is close but not really what I need - as far as I know, you can't change which files/folders Air includes when packaging the APK, right? 'cause it's not code I want to include conditionally, it's folders full of external asssets

Comment: If Flash can run a `.bat`/`.bash` file before building the APK, then you can use that to copy in the relevant folders. That, or look into ANT, which is pretty much what that allows you to do - you just separate the build process from the development process. A long time ago I used ANT to build a web, desktop and playbook version using different project files and assets, but the same source - call ANT once and get produce 3 different builds at a time